# Proving n'th derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ by induction

Tags: calculus, derivatives, induction

I don't really know how to prove by induction the n'th derivative of $\sqrt{x}$.
I found out that $f^{(n)} = (-1)^{(n-1)} \frac{(2n-1)!}{(n-1)!2^{2n-1}}x^{\frac{1}{2}-n}$ for $n>0$. I already showed that it holds for n=1, but now I'm stuck and I don't know how to show that it holds for k+1. I tried to do it this way $ \frac {d^{k+1}}{dx^{k+1}} (\sqrt x)= \frac {d}{dx}((-1)^{(k-1)} \frac{(2k-1)!}{(k-1)!2^{2k-1}}x^{\frac{1}{2}-k})$ but it's so hard do derivate this expression. Is it maybe some way to prove it by Taylor polynomial or whatever else? Could somebody please help me?

Comment: Consider $(-1)^{(k-1)} \frac{(2k-1)!}{(k-1)!2^{2k-1}}$ as a *constant term* with respect to $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint :

$$\frac {d}{dx}\left((-1)^{(k-1)} \frac{(2k-1)!}{(k-1)!2^{2k-1}}x^{\frac{1}{2}-k}\right) = (-1)^{(k-1)}{(2k-1)!\over(k-1)!2^{2k-1}}{d\over dx}\left(x^{{1\over2}-k}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

To get a systematic expression for the derivatives, read them off by comparing the form of the Taylor expansion $f(x+h)=f(x)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty f^{(k)}(x)·\frac{h^k}{k!}$ with Newtons binomial series,
\begin{align}
\sqrt{x+h}&=\sqrt{x}(1+\tfrac hx)^{\frac12}
=\sqrt{x}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\tbinom{\frac12}{k}(\tfrac hx)^k
\\&=\sqrt{x}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}·\tfrac12(1-\tfrac12)(2-\tfrac12)…(k-1-\tfrac12)·x^{-k+\frac12}·\frac{h^k}{k!}
\\&=\sqrt{x}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}·\frac{(2k-2)!}{2^{2k-1}(k-1)!}·x^{-k+\frac12}·\frac{h^k}{k!}
\end{align}